# mvim: display number of columns in window?

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim

I'm transitioning to MacVim from terminal vim, and I've gotten used to the "80 x 24" display at the top of terminal windows (COLS x ROWS). Is there a way to enable some such display in MacVim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence the title of the GVIM window with the `'titlestring'` option, e.g. like this:

```
:set titlestring=%{&columns}\ x\ %{&lines}
```

I don't know whether MacVim supports this, though. If yes, `:set title?` should print `title`.

Comment: MacVim does indeed support this. Thank you ;)